# R password analysis

Tags: r, passwords, analytics

I want to analyse passwords for a uni project. I would like to give R 50 passwords to analyse, looking at the combinations of lower case, upper case, numbers and special characters. I am working with some R code, taken from https://datadrivensecurity.info/blog/posts/2014/Feb/ripal/ and I cant get it work.

Specifically R is only recognising lower case letter passwords, I cant get it to recognise the passwords which have other combinations of characters, such as upper and lower case, lower and special etc, the code keeps coming back with 0% when I know there are passwords which fit that criteria in 50 from my data frame.

Is there something I am doing wrong, are my arguments / R code correct?

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
  contains.only.lower.alpha <- sum(grepl("^[a-z]+$",Final_DF$Pswd))
contains.only.upper.alpha <- sum(grepl("^[A-Z]+$",Final_DF$Pswd))
contains.only.numeric <- sum(grepl("^[0-9]+$",Final_DF$Pswd))
contains.only.special <- sum(grepl("^[:punct:]+$",Final_DF$Pswd))

contains.both.lower.and.upper <- only.lower.alpha + only.upper.alpha
contains.both.lower.and.numeric <- only.lower.alpha + only.numeric
contains.both.lower.and.special <- only.lower.alpha + only.special
contains.both.upper.and.numeric <- only.upper.alpha + only.numeric
contains.both.upper.and.special <- only.upper.alpha + only.special
contains.both.numeric.and.special <- only.numeric + only.special

contains.lower.upper.and.numeric <- only.lower.alpha + only.upper.alpha + only.numeric
contains.lower.upper.numeric.and.special <- only.lower.alpha + only.upper.alpha + only.numeric + only.special

print(sprintf("Only lowercase alpha = %d, (%3.3f%%)", only.lower.alpha, 100*(only.lower.alpha/50)))
print(sprintf("Only uppercase alpha = %d, (%3.3f%%)", only.upper.alpha, 100*(only.upper.alpha/50)))
print(sprintf("Only numeric = %d, (%3.3f%%)", only.numeric, 100*(only.numeric/50)))
print(sprintf("Only special = %d, (%3.3f%%)", only.special, 100*(only.special/50)))

print(sprintf("Both lower and upper alpha = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.lower.and.upper, 100*(both.lower.and.upper/50)))
print(sprintf("Both lower and numeric = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.lower.and.numeric, 100*(both.lower.and.numeric/50)))
print(sprintf("Both lower and special = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.lower.and.special, 100*(both.lower.and.special/50)))
print(sprintf("Both upper and numeric = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.upper.and.numeric, 100*(both.upper.and.numeric/50)))
print(sprintf("Both upper and special = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.upper.and.special, 100*(both.upper.and.special/50)))
print(sprintf("Both.numeric.and.special = %d, (%3.3f%%)", both.numeric.and.special, 100*(both.numeric.and.special/50)))

print(sprintf("Lower.upper.and.numeric = %d, (%3.3f%%)", lower.upper.and.numeric, 100*(lower.upper.and.numeric/50)))
print(sprintf("Lower.upper.numeric.and.special = %d, (%3.3f%%)", lower.upper.numeric.and.special, 100*(lower.upper.numeric.and.special/50)))
```

These are the 50 passwords I am working with, which I have generated using R, I will regenerate these to get a greater spread to include all special etc after I know I can get the code to work.

```
> Final_DF$Pswd
```

[1] "monkey"       "iloveyou"     "dragon"       "jbI2pnK$xi"   "password"     "computer"     "!qessw"
[8] "tUNh&SSm6!"   "sunshine"     "wYrUeWV"      "superman"     "samsung"      "utoXGe6$"     "master"
[15] "wjZC&OvXX"    "0R1cNTm9sGir" "Fbuu2bs89?"   "pokemon"      "secret"       "x&W1TjO59"    "buster"
[22] "purple"       "shine"        "flower"       "marina"       "Tg%OQT$0"     "SbDUV&nOX"    "peanut"
[29] "angel"        "?1LOEc4Zfk"   "computer"     "spiderman"    "nothing"      "$M6LgmQgv$"   "orange"
[36] "knight"       "american"     "outback"      "TfuRpt3PiZ"   "air"          "surf"         "lEi2a$$eyz"
[43] "date"         "V$683rx$p"    "newcastle"    "estate"       "foxy"         "ginger"       "coffee"
[50] "legs"

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Where are `lower.upper.and.numeric` & `lower.upper.numeric.and.special`? I agree with Ronak in that we need a sample input (using `dput`) and an expected output. What is the `/50` designed to do here? The problem with the methodology is that you are looking specifically for strings that are only numbers eg `124234` or only lowercase eg `abcas` and then trying to combine those two pieces of logic to find if `123abc` is in there. You would need to allow for other value to be in the string eg `contains.upper.alpha <- grepl("^.*[A-Z]+.*$",Final_DF$Pswd)`

Comment: Hi @JonnyPhelps the 50 is the total number of passwords being examined, I use it to calculate the %.

Comment: I think I need to tidy up / make the values more self explanatory, contains is a much better way of explaining that password being examined has upper and lower case etc. Issue at the moment is I cant get R to recognise and count a password which has both upper and lower case

Comment: Something like `data <- "abcABC"; grepl("^.*[a-z]+.*$",data) & grepl("^.*[A-Z]+.*$",data)`. You want conditions that checks if there are any lowercase or any uppercase then combine them. So you could wrap this in the sum ie do the sum after doing the combined logic test

Comment: @RonakShah, I have provided the data I am working with, if that helps

Comment: @JonnyPhelps thanks, I have tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work how I would like,  [1] "abcABC"
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[19] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE. Password number 4 for example is jbI2pnK$xi, which this new code reads as true, when it should be false as it contains lower, upper, numbers and special characters

Comment: I know that my password list contains 34 x lower case only passwords, 2 x passwords which have only lower and upper case, 1 x password with lower case and special, 2 x with lower, upper and special, 11 x with lower, upper, numbers and special

Comment: The test does work for `jbI2pnK$xi` as it does have a lower and an upper case. You need to extend that logic eg if you want lower, upper and special then you need to keep stacking the conditions eg `grepl("^.*[a-z]+.*$",data) & grepl("^.*[A-Z]+.*$",data) & grepl(".*^[:punct:]+.*$")`

Comment: So define the base conditions for containing lower, upper, special etc. then combine them as you need and then sum at the end. You can replace the 50 with `nrow(Final_DF)` to standardise that out

Comment: Also, please share data with `dput` and copy that output :)

Comment: @JonnyPhelps sorry I cant get dput to work in comments, any ideas? Using your last example I get two outputs of TRUE for tUNh&SSm6! and utoXGe6$, which contain lower, upper, special and numbers, when I only wanted lower, upper and special. I am wondering if the logic needs to include exclude arguments, using regex etc so R knows not to include tUNh&SSm6! in this search as it contains a number and does not fit the criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, needed combination of logic statements for each password character combination

```
grepl("^(?!.*[[:lower:]]).*$",df, perl = TRUE)
```